# How to setSelectedItem OR setSelectedIndex to DefaultComboBoxModel from table object

Tags: java, swing, casting, jcombobox, defaulttablemodel

Class ComboItem

```
public class ComboItems {

    private Long key;
    private String value;

    public ComboItems(Long key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }

    public Long getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Set Class ComboItem to ComboBox

```
private void loadSupplier(FormBuy formBuy) {
        List<Supplier> suppliers = supplierJdbc.selectSuppliers("%%");
        DefaultComboBoxModel defaultComboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        suppliers.forEach(supplier -> {
            defaultComboBoxModel.addElement(new ComboItems(supplier.getId(), supplier.getName()));
        });
        formBuy.getjComboBoxSupplier().setModel(defaultComboBoxModel);
    }
```

Show to DefautTableModel

```
    private void loadTable(DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel, FormBuy formBuy) {
            defaultTableModel.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
            defaultTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
            

List<ResponseListTableBuy> buys = buyJdbc.selectBuys("%" + formBuy.getjTextFieldSearch().getText() + "%");
        Object[] objects = new Object[10];
        for (ResponseListTableBuy buy : buys) {
            objects[0] = buy.getId();
            objects[1] = buy.getSupplier().getName();
            objects[2] = buy.getCategory().getName();
            objects[3] = buy.getItem().getName();
            objects[4] = buy.getUnit().getName();
            objects[5] = buy.getCountItem();
            objects[6] = buy.getBuyPrice();
            objects[7] = new BigDecimal(buy.getCountItem() * buy.getBuyPrice().intValue());
            objects[8] = buy.getSellPrice();
            objects[9] = buy.getDate();
            defaultTableModel.addRow(objects);
        }
}
```

so far it's still fine!. I got an error when I put this code

get code from table to combobox

```
formBuy.getjComboBoxSupplier().getModel().setSelectedItem(defaultTableModel.getValueAt(formBuy.getjTableBuy().getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
```

and put this an error

```
System.out.println(((ComboItems) formBuy.getjComboBoxSupplier().getModel().getSelectedItem()).getKey());

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to aliimron.combobox.ComboItems
    at aliimron.controller.ControllerBuy$1.mouseClicked(ControllerBuy.java:97)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6542)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4544)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

so the flow is from comboitem to combobox to table and back from table to combobox. how do you get it from the table back into the combobox

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: The class name should NOT be ComboItems. the "Items" implies multiple objects. Instead it should just be `ComboItem`, since each instance represents a single item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you build your model using ...

```
defaultComboBoxModel.addElement(new ComboItems(supplier.getId(), supplier.getName()));
```

This is good, you're encapsulating the information into an object, but, then you use

```
formBuy.getjComboBoxSupplier().getModel().setSelectedItem(defaultTableModel.getValueAt(formBuy.getjTableBuy().getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
```

Wait, that's a lot, lets see if we can clean it up a bit...

```
formBuy
    .getjComboBoxSupplier()
    .getModel()
    .setSelectedItem(
        defaultTableModel.getValueAt(
            formBuy.getjTableBuy().getSelectedRow(), 1
        ).toString()
    );
```

So, basically, you're trying to use a `String` to set the value of the model, but the model is expecting an instance of `ComboItems` ...

So, you have a couple of choices...

## #1. You could...

Supply the `TableModel` with a `ComboItems` and then use a custom cell renderer to render it, then you could use something like...

```
formBuy
    .getjComboBoxSupplier()
    .getModel()
    .setSelectedItem(
        (ComboItems)defaultTableModel.getValueAt(
            formBuy.getjTableBuy().getSelectedRow(), 1
        )
    );
```

to set the selected combo box item.

For my money, this is the more "correct" approach, see

- [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- [Editors and Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

for more details

## #2. You could...

Look up the item in the model directly, based on the `String` from the table.

Something maybe like this...

```
String value = (String)defaultTableModel.getValueAt(formBuy.getjTableBuy().getSelectedRow(), 1);

DefaultComboBoxModel model = formBuy.getjComboBoxSupplier().getModel()
for (int index = 0; index < model.getSize(); index++) {
    ComboItems items = (ComboItems) model.getElementAt(index);
    if (items.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
        formBuy
            .getjComboBoxSupplier()
            .getModel()
            .setSelectedItem(items);
        break;
    }
}
```

But to be honest, you're better off with option #1

## Extensions...

One of things I might be focusing on, is trying to tie your data together, in a more meaningful way, so you don't need to do these "side lookups", for example, your data seems to be expressible as a key/value pair, lets start there...

```
public interface KeyValueExpressible {
    public String getKey();
    public String getValue();
}

public abstract class AbstractKeyValue implements KeyValueExpressible {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    public AbstractKeyValue(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    
}
```

Okay, but how's that going to help you?  Well, now you can narrow the constraints to actual data types, for example...

```
public class Supplier extends AbstractKeyValue {

    public Supplier(String key, String value) {
        super(key, value);
    }
    
}
```

The neat thing is, this is still usable anywhere you need `KeyValueExpressible`, but can provide a finer level constraint when you need the `Supplier`, sweet

Now you could construct you combobox using something like...

```
List<Supplier> suppliers = supplierJdbc.selectSuppliers("%%");
DefaultComboBoxModel<KeyValueExpressible> defaultComboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
suppliers.forEach(supplier -> {
    defaultComboBoxModel.addElement(supplier);
});
formBuy.getjComboBoxSupplier().setModel(defaultComboBoxModel);
```

*nb:* `DefaultComboBoxModel<KeyValueExpressible>` could also be `DefaultComboBoxModel<Supplier>`, but `DefaultComboBoxModel<KeyValueExpressible>` allows us to do cool magic like...

```
public class KeyValueExpressibleListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        if (value instanceof KeyValueExpressible) {
            KeyValueExpressible keyValue = (KeyValueExpressible) value;
            setText(keyValue.getValue());
        }
        return this;
    }
}
// Why doesn't DefaultListCellRenderer support generics
```

which can then be applied using something like...

```
JComboBox<KeyValueExpressible> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(defaultComboBoxModel);
comboBox.setRenderer(new KeyValueExpressibleListCellRenderer());
```

Which is nice a reusable, sweet.

Now, we can start extending the concept, for example, assuming we have something like...

```
public interface ResponseListTableBuy {
    public String getId();
    public Supplier getSupplier();
    //...
}
```

Then we can encapsulate the `TableModel`, for example...

```
public class BuyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    
    private List<ResponseListTableBuy> buys;
    
    private String[] columnNames = new String[]{
        "id",
        "Supplier",
        "Category",
        "Item",
        "Unit",
        "Count",
        "Buy price",
        "Total",
        "Sell price",
        "Date"
    };

    public BuyTableModel(List<ResponseListTableBuy> buys) {
        this.buys = buys;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return buys.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0: return String.class;
            case 1: return KeyValueExpressible.class;
            case 2: return KeyValueExpressible.class;
            case 3: return KeyValueExpressible.class;
            case 4: return KeyValueExpressible.class;
            case 5: return Integer.class;
            case 6: return Double.class;
            case 7: return BigDecimal.class;
            case 8: return Double.class;
            case 9: return LocalDate.class;
        }
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        ResponseListTableBuy buy = buys.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0: return buy.getId();
            case 1: return buy.getSupplier();
            case 2: return buy.getCategory();
            case 3: return buy.getItem();
            case 4: return buy.getUnit();
            case 5: return buy.getCountItem();
            case 6: return buy.getBuyPrice();
            // This should be a computed porperty, just saying...
            case 7: return new BigDecimal(buy.getCountItem() * buy.getBuyPrice().intValue());;
            case 8: return buy.getSellPrice();
            case 9: return buy.getDate();
        }
    }
    
}
```

And then....

```
public class KeyValueExpressibleTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (value instanceof KeyValueExpressible) {
            KeyValueExpressible keyValue = (KeyValueExpressible) value;
            setText(keyValue.getValue());
        }
        return this;
    }
    
}
```

more magic !

You apply it using something like...

```
JTable table = new JTable();
table.setDefaultRenderer(KeyValueExpressible.class, new KeyValueExpressibleTableCellRenderer());
```

And suddenly, every column you said was a `KeyValueExpressible.class` will be rendered through this renderer! Sweet!

We've encapsulated the data in the model; we've got the view to render the data the way want it to and when needed...we can do...

```
formBuy
    .getjComboBoxSupplier()
    .getModel()
    .setSelectedItem(
        (KeyValueExpressible)defaultTableModel.getValueAt(
            formBuy.getjTableBuy().getSelectedRow(), 1
        )
    );
```

*nb: You could make the `BuyTableModel` do the casting for you, but I think I might have already blown your mind*

### A neat little trick...

You might find yourself in a situation where you have two instances `KeyValueExpressible` representing the same data (you could use a common factory to manage it, but that's another topic).

In those cases, you need some way to tell that those two instances are the same, this is where `equals` and `hashCode` come in, for example...

```
public abstract class AbstractKeyValue implements KeyValueExpressible {

    private String key;
    private String value;

    public AbstractKeyValue(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj instanceof KeyValueExpressible) {
            return false;
        }
        KeyValueExpressible keyValue = (KeyValueExpressible) obj;
        return keyValue.getKey().equals(getKey()) && keyValue.getValue().equals(getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.key);
        hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.value);
        return hash;
    }
    
}
```

Now, any two instances with the same `key` and `value` will be equal, sweet!

Now, if you prefer to tighten the constraint a little more, you could also do something like...

```
public class Supplier extends AbstractKeyValue {

    public Supplier(String key, String value) {
        super(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Supplier) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.equals(obj);
    }

}
```

Now only two `Supplier`s with the same key/value will be equal, sweet!